# PHP: Value not saving in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

PHP Code:

```
$file = file_get_contents('example.com/index/');
$array = array();
preg_match_all('!href=\\"(/img/[0-9]+.jpg)\\"!u', $file, $array);
$results = array_unique($array[1]);

foreach ( $results as $value ) {
    $value = 'imgaes.example.com/' . $value;
    echo "$value\n"; // imgaes.example.com/838.jpg
}

var_dump($results); // 838.jpg
```

Where is the error? I try make a little grabber. Its all details, i think.

Comment: I really don't understand what you meant, you don't change the value of $results so it stays the same ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign the value by reference:

```
foreach ( $results as &$value ){
  ...
}

unset($value);
```

Answer (score 2):

or

```
foreach ( $results as $key => $value ) {
    $results[$key] = 'imgaes.example.com' . $value;
    echo "$value\n"; // imgaes.example.com/img/838.jpg
}

var_dump($results);
```